# How do I put a dollar sign when using printf in java?

Tags: java, printf

I want to put a dollar sign in front of the variable `price` and keep the same format but if I just put it in front of the `%36` it will be around 36 characters away.

`System.out.printf("  Sale Price %36.2f", price);`

Comment: The first problem of this code is that you should never use `float` or `double` for currencies. Bette use for example `int` or `long` and calculate in dollar-cent instead.

Comment: Or use a `BigDecimal`

Comment: Take a look at Oracle's tutorial [on currencies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html)

Comment: Actually you shouldn't work just up to cents if you are working for something that requires more precision, like a currency converter

Comment: sorry to waste time I just thought I would ask if it was possible with this specific line of code or if I had to use a different format in order to achieve this. But now I will know in the future to rather use an int or long for currencies. I wrote a decent size program and when I finished the whole receipt I relized I didn't have any dollar signs.

Comment: a bit dirty but simple... `System.out.printf("  Sale Price $%-36.2f", price)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
NumberFormat nf=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
System.out.printf("  Sale Price %36s", nf.format(price));
```

Basically use the currency number format and format it as the string you want. Then you use the %36 to print the resulting string at the position you want.

Result:

```
Sale Price                               $12.30
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it works perfectly. But for future reference does the .getCurrencyInstance format make so there are only 2 decimal places after and rounds them up if necessary?

Comment: It uses the locale of the system to find the currency sign and the default currency format. You can use setMaximumFractionDigits and setMinimumFractionDigits to control the number format. For example setMaximumFractionDigits(1) will make it have just 1 digit after the dot

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you

```
DecimalFormat ft = new DecimalFormat("####"); 
double price = 23456.789; 
ft = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.##"); 
System.out.println("Sale Price: " + ft.format(price));
```

answer is

```
Sale Price: $23,456.79
```